# Error when classifying class with LibTorch on a trained model

Tags: c++, libtorch

We plan to use Visual Studio 2019 to load a model that has already been trained in PyTorch with Script conversion into C++ with CUDA 11.3 and LibTorch 1.11 for class classification. Input image is a black and white image, input size is 224x224. Therefore, the tensor size is `{1,1,224,224}`.

Here is the current code, and as an example, we are currently inputting a sample tensor with no image input.

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    // Load the model
    std::string model_path = "model_weights_c++.pt";
    torch::jit::script::Module module;
    try {
        module = torch::jit::load(model_path);
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error loading the model: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the device to GPU if available
    torch::Device device(torch::kCPU);
    if (torch::cuda::is_available()) {
        device = torch::Device(torch::kCUDA); }
    }

    // Create a vector of inputs.
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(torch::ones({ 1, 1, 224, 224 }));
    module.to(device);

    // Execute the model and turn its output into a tensor.
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> outputs;
    at::Tensor output = module.forward(inputs).toTensor().to(device);
    std::cout << output.slice(/*dim=*/1, /*start=*/0, /*end=*/5) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The build succeeds, but while executing module.forward(), the following program stops the effect with an unhandled exception. [return stack.front()].
What is the reason? Please help.

```
at::IValue operator()(
    Stack stack, kwargs& kwargs& kwargs
    const Kwargs& kwargs = Kwargs()) {
    getSchema().checkAndNormalizeInputs(stack, kwargs);
    run(stack);
    return stack.front(); }
  }
```

[image: Error]

Comment: ***What is the reason?*** Handle the exception and get the error message for it to tell you the reason.

Comment: `Stack stack, kwargs& kwargs& kwargs` What? That's not valid code.

Comment: If `stack` is empty is `stack.front();` still valid?

Comment: Added images of call history and error screens.

Comment: So @JesperJuhl is most likely correct. The stack is empty.

Comment: @drescherjm
If you run without pushing to the stack, you will get another error. Therefore, the stack is not considered empty. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The most likely reason for `return stack.front();` to cause this error is the stack is empty when it was called. However it could also be some other undefined behavior like heap corruption.  In either case you need to investigate the error with your debugger.